# What kind of mushroom goes well with Tandoori Chicken on a pizza?

Tags: pizza, herbs, mushrooms

I was thinking of making a pizza with the following ingredients which I found on [reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/j487a/iama_former_45_year_veteran_dominos_pizza/c2900c0).  I'm looking for a dream team of herbs, spices and mushrooms to complete this.

- Sun dried tomato and garlic sauce
- Extra Cheese
- Onions
- Mushroom
- Roquito Peppers
- Tandoori Chicken
- Chorizo (Optional)
- Herbs

What kind of mushrooms would you use?  I was also wondering if anyone had any ideas for the herbs besides fresh basil, and oregano?

Answer (score 1):

Not the question you asked, but properly done tandoori chicken or Mexican chorizo will completely mask all of the other flavors you list.  Subbing a simple grilled chicken and Spanish chorizo makes for a nice savory pizza (indeed, I had just that pizza last night, without chorizo).  In that case, simple white, button, or crimini mushrooms (the latter sometime sold as "baby portabello") will give a nice earthy note without breaking the bank.   Saute' them before putting them on the pizza for maximal flavor and minimal chewiness.

As for herbs, basil and oregano are obvious, and nothing else is required.  Marjoram and/or nutmeg would be okay. Lemongrass would be interesting but maybe overkill.

Answer (score -1):

I would use sliced button, because they have very little flavor, and cook down to almost nothing. Also, they are very cheap.

Comment: Wait, what? Why would you waste precious pizza real estate on something that doesn't lend flavor? Dave's answer notes they'll impart an earthy note, which makes sense to me...